# CFBuilder as Eclipse Plugin Won't Open

Tags: eclipse, coldfusion, coldfusionbuilder

I'm having a very odd issue installing ColdFusion Build 2.0 Update 1 as a plugin for Eclipse. I don't want to install it Standalone because I'd like to also install some other Eclipse plugins, and have read there are performance issues with the Standalone version.

I've tried `eclipse.exe -clean`, though I have a fresh install of Eclipse. I have uninstalled CF Builder (multiple times), installed with and without (explicitly given) Admin privileges.

When the installation completes, Eclipse opens. I select a new, empty Workspace. Eclipse opens as it normally would (no CF Builder license prompt as I see in some installation tutorials), and NO CF Builder perspective is available. I see some CF Builder menu options under Help, but they won't open either.

The installation log doesn't note anything that I see that would say the installation failed. Everything seems to be installing correctly.

I have to say that I do have multiple Eclipse installs, one being Aptana, on my machine.

Any help with this installation would be appreciated.

Thank you!

Edit:
I am using Eclipse Kepler 64 bit. Java 7 64 bit.

```
Eclipse Standard/SDK
Version: Kepler Service Release 1
Build id: 20130919-0819
```

Comment: Which version of Eclipse?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ColdFusion Builder 2.x will only run on Eclipse v3.7.x. That's not a minimum version, that's the *only* version.

Kepler seems to be v4.3, so is not supported. And by "not supported" means "won't run".

Ref: "[Installation considerations](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusionBuilder/2.0/Installing/WSf23b27ebc7b554b6-8233a4136623ee332-7ffd.html)"

Comment: I'll give that version a try. I was under the impression I could use any version of Eclipse newer than 3.6. The instructions to install CF Builder plug-in state "Ensure that Eclipse 3.6 or a higher version is installed on your computer."

Comment: Yes, they do say that. However Adobe clarified it's 3.7.x and that's as high as it goes. I could not find the blog article they said it in.

Comment: Is there a reason you're running it as a plugin rather than just doing a standalone CFBuilder?

Comment: I've seen several blog posts like this one: http://cfmlblog.adamcameron.me/2013/04/coldfusion-builder-on-64-bit-is-really.html. I'm also working with TFS and wanting to use the Eclipse TFS plugin, amongst other Eclipse plugins. Do any/most Eclipse plugins install into CFBuilder?

Comment: Ha, I now see in that article that you also mention having this same issue (using too new an Eclipse version). I should have read it closer. Though it does look like 3.8.x would work as well. Thanks, Adam.

Comment: @PeterBoughton it's a lot more responsive as a plug-in, as one can use 64-bit Eclipse.

Comment: Heh. Well I would have said "sure, there's no reason for any Eclipse plugins not to install into CFBuilder", but then prior to Adam's comment I would have also said "of course there'll be a standalone 64-bit CFBuilder" - because again there's no reason for there not to be. Well, no reason except Adobe being Adobe... :/